# "have got..." in negative statements

Tags: grammar

I have got some questions about **a** and **any**?

Which are correct?

> 1. I have not got **any**/**a** meeting?
> 2. I have not got **any**/**a** problem?

Answer (score 1):

*Have (not) got* (in the sense of *(not) have*) is colloquial **spoken** English; it shouldn't be used in writing, except in informal txts with friends.

And whether it's spoken or written, you need to contract it; no native English speaker would say

- *I have not got a meeting.*

(unless they were reading aloud something written by another, or denying some assertion);
rather,

- *I haven't got a meeting,*

is a normal sentence, with stress on *got*. Indeed, in speech, the /h/ in *I haven't* is often omitted, though English typography hasn't got a handy apostrophical sign for that.

Failure to contract auxiliaries (especially with *not*) is a very clear sign of a speaker who's not comfortable with the spoken language; listen for contractions and practice them. Native speakers don't make mistakes in contracting, whatever you may have been taught, and there are many forms to get accustomed to; and UK and US contractions can be different.

As for *a* versus *any*, you can always use *a* (with the right noun, of course), but *any* is a Negative Polarity Item, which means it can only be used in a negative context. Following *not* is a negative context, so *any* is fine with *not*. But don't use it without a negative.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences would use “a” and not “any.” “Any” can only be used if the object (the thing that you are talking about) is plural.

I have not got **a meeting**.
I have not got **any meetings**.